# Show current location of user on an offline static image (jpeg) - Android

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, coordinates, geo

**Background / Concept:** I want to create an application that can help user searching for specific things. Let say nearby restaurants. Here I want to include an offline map covering 1 km area around that restaurant, (its easy i can take snap of google map).

**Problem:** is it possible to indicate current user position on that static image file? I have some idea that I note the Lat / Long of all four corners of that image, take user current position, do some calculation and show the current spot.. But I m not sure where to start and if there is already a good optimized solution.

If I can show current user direction (heading) it will be awesome!

**MORE CONCISE QUESTION:**
I have a jpeg image (which is actually a street map) and I know lat / long of all four corners of image. How can i show current user location on that image?

*P.S. The application is suppose to work without data connection, so I can't load google map etc*

Comment: What's the final question here? Is it about map tiling or about Android UI? For the tile you can use a GeoTIFF, which includes a location embedded with the `*.tif` file.

Comment: Debracey, I added more clarification in the question, thanks

Comment: That doesn't clarify much of anything. JPEG does not have any location embedding capabilities. Either store that alongside the image (in an XML for example) or use something the supports embedded locations (e.g., GeoTIFF)

Comment: I want to achieve it by calculation and I believe its possible. Just now sure about best solution or where to start. I m also looking into GeoTIFF. I just heard it from you. Thanks

Comment: If you know lat long of all corners, then you know the how many pixels, x and y, represent degrees.  There are many calculations available through a Google search to calculate distance and bearing between lat long.  For the pixel calc, just represent lat long as decimal degrees

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say that user position is uLat and uLon, and the map have top left corner tlLat and tlLon, and bottom right corner brLat and brLon. Finally, map size is x and y pixels.

```
userX = x*(uLon-tlLon)/(brLon-tlLon);
userY = y-y*(uLat-brLat)/(tlLat-brLat);
```

This is an aproximation that only works for small distances (1 km should be fine) as it's not taking into consideration the earth curvature.

I'm not sure that's legal to use google map screenshot without authorization.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks Luis, yeah I m a bit concerned with google maps as well.. was thinking of putting a mark that image has been taken from google map etc. Any idea if I can get some free images of different locations other then google map? I dont mind putting a copy right note.

Comment: I believe you can take them from http://www.openstreetmap.org/. You can even contribute to improve the maps they have.

Comment: by the way, you can also have a look at http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/. They have an API for android that works offline using openstreet maps.

Comment: awesome, will check both resources.